# Why does this throw java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, wait, synchronized, illegalmonitorstateexcep

This problem is from Leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/print-zero-even-odd/

This is my code:

```
class ZeroEvenOdd {
    private int n;
    
    State state;
    Type prevState = Type.EVEN;
    int count = 1;
    public ZeroEvenOdd(int n) {
        this.n = n;
        state = new State(Type.ZERO);
    }

    // printNumber.accept(x) outputs "x", where x is an integer.
    public void zero(IntConsumer printNumber) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized(state){
            while(state.type != Type.ZERO){
                state.wait();
            }
            
            printNumber.accept(0);
            
            if(prevState == Type.EVEN)
                state.type = Type.ODD;
            else
                state.type = Type.EVEN;
                
        }
       state.notifyAll();

    }

    public  void even(IntConsumer printNumber) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized(state){
            while(state.type != Type.EVEN){
                state.wait();
            }
            
            printNumber.accept(count);
            count++;
            prevState = state.type;
            state.type = Type.ZERO;

        }     
        
         state.notifyAll();

    }

    public  void odd(IntConsumer printNumber) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized(state){
            while(state.type != Type.ODD){
                state.wait();
            }
            
            printNumber.accept(count);
            count++;
            prevState = state.type;
            state.type = Type.ZERO;
        }    
            state.notifyAll();

    }
    
    public class State{
        
        public Type type;
        
        public State(Type type){
            this.type = type;
        }
    }
    
    public enum Type {
        ZERO, ODD, EVEN
    }
}
```

We need to print `01020304050`

Getting the following error : `Thrown exception java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException`

Not sure where I went wrong? I'm a newbie to Multi-threading and concurrency. Can anyone please help?

Thank you.

Comment: Someone already has the solution for most of these LeetCode tasks here - 
https://github.com/RodneyShag/LeetCode_solutions/blob/master/Solutions/Print%20Zero%20Even%20Odd.md - Including the one you're looking for

Comment: @shikida Thank you! Can you even point out what's wrong with my code? I don't get why  I'm getting that error?

Comment: IllegalMonitorStateException means you're calling wait() and notify() from unsynchronized methods, I guess -- take a look on this explanation https://www.programmersought.com/article/20516914238/

Comment: Thank you! Now, I'm getting a whole different issue

Comment: The solution to a problem changes the nature of the problem.